# Trademark replace in underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

My code below in my HTML underscore template is literally printing out

```
 "<sup>&reg;</sup>"
```

on the page instead of the trademark replacement (<sup>®</sup>) I want the below code to do. What's wrong with my code? EDIT: I want designation.title and designation.description to print to the page, just replace the (R) in there with <sup>®</sup>.

```
<%- designation.title.replace(/(®)/ig, "<sup>&reg;</sup>") %>
<%- designation.description.replace(/(®)/ig, "<sup>&reg;</sup>")%>
```

Comment: I don't know underscore, but it seems you're seeing the *text*, instead of the *HTML*, of the element.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I'm seeing the text and not the HTML. But not sure why

Answer (score 2):

You're using the type of [template function](http://underscorejs.org/#template) that does automatic escaping for HTML: `<%-` instead of `<%`. Using that will cause underscore to escape everything so that it can be output as is (output without being interpreted as HTML, so `<` becomes `&lt;`, `&` becomes `&amp;`, etc.

If you want to output raw HTML just drop the `-` off `<%-`, but that can be unsafe, depending on the rest of `designation.title` and if it has any characters that need escaping.

Comment: I see what you're saying. But if I want to print the content of designation.title and replace any (R) text with the trademark, how do I write this in underscore? Because I do want <%- designation.title %>

Comment: @sk_225 I don't think underscore templates are powerful enough to do that nicely. The only way I can think of is to do the replacement after the template is rendered: `_.template( '<%- designation.title %>' )( { designation: { title: 'Example®' } } ).replace(/(®)/ig, "<sup>&reg;</sup>")`. It is safe to do that replacement after rending, as long as you don't have any other `®` elsewhere in the template that you don't want to do that replacement to.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<%=` instead.

[`<%-` escapes HTML, `<%=` does not.](http://underscorejs.org/#template)

Answer (score 0):

Create a DOM element and put your string in it.  In your case, hand the el object to the method, not the string?

```js
var output = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var output2 = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
var el = document.createElement( 'div' );
el.innerHTML = "<sup>&reg;</sup>";

var content = document.createTextNode("<sup>&reg;</sup>");

output.appendChild(el);

// this does not work
output2.appendChild(content);
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```